# what is the path to adb binary installation

Tags: paths, adb

In a executable script,I need to add Path to adb binary as follows

```
# 1. Configure where your ADB binary is installed
export AdbCmd="<Path_to_ADB_Binary>"
```

So what is the path in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: "which adb" will tell you

Comment: How many are there?

Comment: Run `locate adb | grep bin` or just `whereis adb`. That should give you a list of paths (if the binary is called `adb` its path should be on that list).

Comment: `locate adb | grep bin` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the path for a specific binary installation,open a terminal and run.

`locate <name of binary> | grep bin`

For example.

`locate adb | grep bin`

This will give an output as follows.

```
aditya@aditya-desktop:~$locate adb |grep bin  
/home/ubuntu-builder/FileSystem/sbin/badblocks  
/home/ubuntu-builder/FileSystem/usr/bin/mbadblocks  
/sbin/badblocks  
/usr/bin/adb  
/usr/bin/mbadblocks
```

From this list,You may use the required path.

**NOTE:-** locate is not realtime. If you install adb and then use locate it will not find the binary. You first need to update (or wait for it to update) the database `locate` uses.In such case `whereis` can be used.

To use `whereis`,open a terminal and type

```
whereis <name of binary>
```

For example.

```
whereis adb
```

This will give an output as follows.

```
aditya@aditya-desktop:~$ whereis adb
adb: /usr/bin/adb /usr/bin/X11/adb /usr/share/man/man1/adb.1.gz
```

Comment: locate is not realtime. If you install adb and then use locate it will not find the binairy. You 1st need to update (or wait for it to update) the database locate uses. "which" is better

Answer (score 8):

default path of adb binary installation on ubuntu:

```
/usr/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

also you can locate path from terminal:

```
locate android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

no matter which os you are using. it always under **android-sdk/platform-tools/**

Answer (score 2):

For those using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio), at the time of writing, the default `adb` on Ubuntu is at

`~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`

---

**Env:**
IDE: Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
SDK: any

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct me, if I am mistaken...

Placing the ADB & Fastbbot binaries in the */usr/bin* folder will give ADB abilities to that User. However, when placed in the */bin* folder at the root of the system, then, all users (even guests) will be able to use ADB & Fastboot.

*Note*: Please use the up-to-date binaries from Android Studio to avoid errors.
Also, It's a good idea to use *copy n' paste* and make a copy instead of removing ADB & Fastboot from that location.

Comment: Location of ADB in Android Studio ...
Android/android-studio/platform-tools/